# How to encrypt your Connection String in Advanced Installer (13.3) Custom Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, advanced-installer

With Advanced Installer, I'm trying to make a Custom Action, that at installationtime, encrypt the Connection String.

I seems like I can't use "~" here. (I moved my working code from the MVC project, to here).

Is there a simple alternative to that line or am I forced to make a complete rewrite and use e.g. a solution that uses somekind of Stream (like this [Modifying Web.Config During Installation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12837/Modifying-Web-Config-During-Installation)

Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the 
    target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: 
    **The application relative virtual path '~' is not allowed here.**

Custom Action:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult EncryptConnStr(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        var cms = section.ConnectionStrings[GetConnectionStringName()];
        var connStr = BuildConnStr(session["CONN_STR_SERVER"], session["CONN_STR_DATABASE"], session["CONN_STR_USERNAME"], session["CONN_STR_PASSWORD"]);

        if (cms == null)
        {
            // Add new Connection String
            section.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(GetConnectionStringName(), connStr));
        }
        else
        {
            // Update existing Connection String
            cms.ConnectionString = connStr;
        }

        // Encrypt
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(ConnStrEncryptionKey);

        // Save the configuration file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look in https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/a-simple-trick-to-centralize-your-net-configurati-1/

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the path issue, is to use `ConfigurationManager` a long with some mapping, like this, instead of the web version `WebConfigurationManager`.

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = path };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

The encryption works fine as the code is, **but the issue with save is still not solved because the execution time is to early. The installation isn't finished and the web.config isn't yet copyed to the `APPDIR`.**